# University's vs Universities', correct spelling of the possessive

Tags: orthography

Something belongs to the University. 
Is it the *Universities' logo* or the *University's logo*? I somehow don't think *University's* exists.

Comment: The fact that the plural form of a word has a different ending from the singular form is completely separate from the issue of adding ***'s*** for the possessive. You always add ***'s*** for the *singular possessive*, irrespective of how you form the plural of the word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the logo belongs to one university, it is the *university's* logo. If the logo is jointly owned by several universities, it is the *universities'* logo.

Comment: Well said - this issue seems to crop up with people surprisingly often, so I think it is good to have a simple and concise answer!

Comment: Agreed, working in leadership at a University it was most helpful to have this answer close at hand.